# SQL Server XML load

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a XML file with this structure

```
<Class>
    <ClassNumber>111</Flight_Number>
        <Student>
            <Student_ID>1</Student_ID>
            <Student_ID>2</Student_ID>
            <Student_ID>3</Student_ID>
        </Student>
    </ClassNumber>
</Class>
<Class>
    <ClassNumber>222</Flight_Number>
        <Student>
            <Student_ID>4</Student_ID>
            <Student_ID>5</Student_ID>
            <Student_ID>6</Student_ID>
        </Student>
    </ClassNumber>
</Class>
```

I want the output to be like

```
111 1
111 2
111 3
222 4
222 5
222 6
```

Please help. I'm trying for a very long time.

Regards,
Frank

Comment: Have a look at the [xml data type methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798). You should use `nodes` and `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that the input you show is not XML:  `</Flight_Number>` does not close any open element, and you do not have a root element for the document.

If the intended input is like the $doc variable in the query below, then the XQuery expression you want will have the structure given here:

```
let $doc := <Classes>
              <Class>
                <ClassNumber>111</ClassNumber>
                <Student>
                  <Student_ID>1</Student_ID>
                  <Student_ID>2</Student_ID>
                  <Student_ID>3</Student_ID>
                </Student>
              </Class>
              <Class>
                <ClassNumber>222</ClassNumber>
                <Student>
                  <Student_ID>4</Student_ID>
                  <Student_ID>5</Student_ID>
                  <Student_ID>6</Student_ID>
                </Student>
              </Class>
            </Classes>
for $s in $doc//Student_ID
return concat($s/../../ClassNumber, ' ', string($s), '&#xA;')
```

In the XQuery engine I used to test this, this produced the desired results:

```
111 1
 111 2
 111 3
 222 4
 222 5
 222 6
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply. Can you give this in SQL server fromat? I'm confused. Sorry abt it...

Comment: Sorry; I know that SQL server supports XQuery, so something in the general shape I gave should work, but I do not have access to a running copy of SQL server so I do not know how the example needs to be modified for use in that product.